# Generating recursive ID by muli-variate group using data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table

I've found several options on how to generate IDs by groups using the `data.table` package in R, but none of them fit my problem exactly. Hopefully someone can help.

In my problem, I have 160 markets that fall within 21 regions in a country. These markets are numbered 1:160 and there may be multiple observations documented within each market. I would like to restructure my market ID variable so that it represents unique markets within each region, and starts counting over again with each new region.

Here's some code to represent my problem:

```
require(data.table)
dt <- data.table(region = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3), 
                 market = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,6,7,7))
> dt
    region market
 1:      1      1
 2:      1      1
 3:      1      2
 4:      1      2
 5:      2      3
 6:      2      3
 7:      2      4
 8:      2      4
 9:      3      5
10:      3      6
11:      3      7
12:      3      7
```

Currently, my data is set up to represent the result of

`dt[, market_new := .GRP, by = .(region, market)]`

But what I'd like get is

```
    region market market_new
 1:      1      1          1
 2:      1      1          1
 3:      1      2          2
 4:      1      2          2
 5:      2      3          1
 6:      2      3          1
 7:      2      4          2
 8:      2      4          2
 9:      3      5          1
10:      3      6          2
11:      3      7          3
12:      3      7          3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to return what you want

```
dt[, market_new:=as.numeric(factor(market)), by=region]
```

here we divide the data up by regions and then give a unique ID to each market in each region via the `factor()` function and extract the underlying numeric index.

Comment: maybe `as.integer`? Oh, alternately `unclass`

Comment: That works perfectly! Thank you. I knew it had to be something simple.

Answer (score 4):

From `1.9.5+`, you can use `frank()` (or `frankv()`) with `ties.method = "dense"` as follows:

```
dt[, market_new := frankv(market, ties="dense"), by=region]
```

Comment: Just a reference. `dt[, market_new := rleid(market), by=region]` produces the same outcome as well.